# Convert a pdf to bmp without external libraries C#

Tags: c#, pdf, bmp

I was wondering if anyone knew how I should approach converting a pdf to bmp in C#. I wanted to do this without external libraries as sort of a longer learning experience.

I'm just stuck as to how to approach this without using other libraries I don't want.

If anyone has any open source examples I could look at to get an idea of how I should start it that would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Interesting to know what you hope to learn out of doing it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558744/c-sharp-pdf-to-bmp-for-free

Comment: @JimHewitt That question is asking about an external application/library, so it's not really what I was asking for.

Comment: @Ahsan Im not entirely sure, I guess I wanted to work more on converting files and learning how to do that by parsing the bytes or other information

Comment: I second @tom_imk's warning about the scope of the project.  This is man-years of work you're talking about, even for people much better qualified than you appear to be.  If you want a fun little programming exercise, try the .ico or .bmp format.  I've written a little tool to muck with .ico's that took me under a week.

Comment: @adv12 Ok cool thanks!

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ce4b3e37-4bec-4506-af15-122c15ac4cfa/convert-pdf-to-any-type-of-image?forum=csharpgeneral 
How about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, obviously you would start with the PDF Reference:
http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf

Then you could try to find an open source PDF renderer and try to understand how they go about rendering stuff.

However I think you underestimate greatly how huge a task you set yourself. Even just extracting some stuff from a PDF and manipulating existing PDFs is very complex. Large companies put huge effort in it and still their libraries do not match with PDF rendering via Acrobat.

Comment: I'll start with that. haha, it's a hefty amount of reading. Yea I probably will end up just finding an open source renderer to learn more about it. Thanks